# Able to access Google Spreadsheet in CSV format, but not JSON format?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-sheets

Using Google's Visualization API, I am trying to access a row in a Google Spreadsheet where the row has a given string in the column called "key".

When I use this code, the success function fires, and I have my data in CSV format:

```
$( ".submit" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
                url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VNr3_0uknNiZct948fPAnVn9mVfepKTqkprB1orS3eo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&tq=select+B,C,D+where+B+matches+%27Osax5Gm8l3Ew3rXx%27&gid=0',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
                error: function(error) { console.log(error.statusText); }
        });
});
```

But when I use this code, with the *only* change being "tgx=out:json" so that I get the data in JSON format, the error function fires. Two particularly frustrating aspects of this: my statusText gives me "OK", and I get no other error messages in my console, so I can't figure out what the error is. Additionally, if I view this URL into my browser, I can see the JSON code just fine -- it only fails when used via this ajax request.

```
$( ".submit" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
                url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VNr3_0uknNiZct948fPAnVn9mVfepKTqkprB1orS3eo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq=select+B,C,D+where+B+matches+%27Osax5Gm8l3Ew3rXx%27&gid=0',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
                error: function(error) { console.log(error.statusText); }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Domain javascript is disabled in most modern browsers by default unless the endpoint server adds a header specifically allowing it. See [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

One way around this is to run some server-side code on your own server to act as a proxy. So your javascript fetches data from the same domain as the page is hosted.